# How do you stop a WebBrowser object in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, browser

How do you stop a `WebBrowser` object in WPF?

The stop method is not an option because that is only available in Windows Forms.

[WebBrowser.Stop Method (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop.aspx_)

And `Dispose` does not seem to be the answer either.

And, now that I mention it. Is there a way of easily finding a corresponding method in WPF that exists in a Windows Form?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate to "about:blank" or

use two WebBrowsers, first visible, second hidden. When you stops first just hide it and show empty second

Comment: I am not using the webbrowser class for its visible properties to the user.  I am using it to navagate several urls in a row.  This can have a wierd effect where the browser starts sending back load completed messages and I just want it stopped.  Doing a swapping tric between two webbrowser classes will not be good enough.

Comment: I agree. just standard solutions do not always contain all that you may need, and sometimes even ugly solutions help out